# Head voice techniques for singing

Tags: technique, voice

My head voice goes a little weaker after an hour of practice (after warm ups). I do take sufficient breaks in between. Is it normal and will it improve with regular practice sessions that I do everyday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weak head voice is a common problem for many singers, but it's definitely something that can be circumvented. Usually, beginners find there's a "*weakening*" in the head range. A weaker head voice also comes from fear or reluctance. There are ways you can strengthen your head voice...

**#### Head Voice Techniques:**

- To work on head voice, the first advice is to focus on breathing.
- If you have perfected your chest voice, then give the same amount of effort in achieving your head voice and never pull off because you might think you may *crack*.
- Again...Breathe, Breathe and Breathe!
- Try maintaining a raised palate and an open space, since it is important to create a space for the voice to resonate in the head; higher range.
- ***A voice strengthening exercise:*** - Talk in a really high pitched voice for a few minutes a day *(the sort of voice you'd put on, like you were doing a puppet show)*
- Keep practicing...You'll surely find some improvements as you go.
- Also, check this [**Singing Lesson**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSGGESKAwVU) on How to access your Head Voice.

Comment: I'd only add that doing breath / diaphragm exercises goes a long way to gaining proper control over your exhalation. Too little air and the voice breaks down into a Fry; too much and you wear our your vocal chords to the point where you fail to hit higher pitches without strain (which wears them out further).